# How to set right method's parameter in Interface class

Tags: c#, oop, interface

Each inherited class's method need different type of parameter.
In this case, how should I define parameter in Interface Method to able to all children method can accept?

```
public interface IPayment 
{
  void MakePayment(OrderInfo orderInfo); // !!
  void MakeRefund (OrderInfo orderInfo); // !!
}

public class OrderInfo 
{
  protected string OrderNo {get; set;}
  protected string CustomerNo { get; set;}
  protected decimal Amount {get; set;}
}

public class CreditCardPaymentInfo : OrderInfo
{
  string CCNum {get; set;}
  string ExpDate { get; set;}
}

public class GooglePaymentInfo : OrderInfo
{
  string GoogleOrderID {get; set;}
}

public class PaypalPaymentInfo : OrderInfo
{
  string PaypalID {get; set;}
}



public void MakePayment()
{
    IPayment paymentModule;
    // Get Order Info 
    if(orderType == "Paypal"){
        paymentModule = new PaypalPayment();

        PaypalPaymentInfo orderInfo = new PaypalPaymentInfo();
        orderInfo.PaypalID = "TEST";
    }else if(orderType == "Google"){
        paymentModule = new GooglePayment();

        GooglePaymentInfo orderInfo = new GooglePaymentInfo();
        orderInfo.GoogleOrderID = "TEST";
    }else{
        paymentModule = new CreditCardPayment();

        CreditCardPaymentInfo orderInfo = new CreditCardPaymentInfo();
        orderInfo.CCNum = "1111111111111111";
        orderInfo.ExpDate = "11/11";
    }

    orderInfo.OrderNo = "123";
    orderInfo.CustomerNo = "ABC";
    orderInfo.Amount = 12.20m;

    paymentModule.MakePayment();
}
```

It occur an error :

> Error 1 'com.WebUI.Models.CreditCardPaymentInfo' does not implement interface member 'com.WebUI.Models.IPaymentProcess.makeRefund(WebUI.Models.RefundModel)'

***[Edit]***

Oh I forgot my Model Code, it's like this,

```
public class CreditCardPayment: IPayment 
{
  public void MakePayment(CreditCardPaymentInfo creditCardPaymentInfo ){...}
  //The parameter type is NOT OrderInfo 
  //public void MakePayment(OrderInfo orderInfo){...}
  public void MakeRefund(CreditCardPaymentInfo creditCardPaymentInfo ){...}
}
```

but in CreditCardPayment case, I need to pass **CreditCardPaymentInfo parameter not OrderInfo** that only contain for common fields.

Comment: The error that you see has nothing to do with what's there in your code, it's because something is missing. Specifically, your classes do not implement `makeRefund`. Passing subclasses of `OrderInfo` to methods expecting "plain" `OrderInfo` is good - it's more or less what *polymorphism* is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public interface IPayment<T> 
    where T: OrderInfo
{
  void MakePayment( T orderInfo );
  void MakeRefund ( T orderInfo );
}
```

Then:

```
public class CreditCardPayment
    : IPayment<CreditCardPaymentInfo>
{
    public void MakePayment( CreditCardPaymentInfo creditCardPaymentInfo ) {
        // ...
    }

    public void MakeRefund( CreditCardPaymentInfo creditCardPaymentInfo ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class CreditCardPaymentInfo
    : OrderInfo
{
    public string CCNum { get; set; }
    public string ExpDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How's that going to help the OP's problem? The question in the title has little to do with the problem he's having.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: making the interface generic sets the right method parameter, as the title says. There are missing parts in his code as we've pointed out though, so the question is actually a bit too vague for now

Comment: The main point is that making the order type parameter a generic type extending `OrderInfo` does not give the OP anything in addition to what he already has.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight agree. The question is vague ;)

Comment: @BlackBear Thank you!, Can I change 'public class CreditCardPaymentInfo' to 'public class CreditCardPaymentInfo:OrderInfo' ? because OrderInfo have common information fields.

Comment: @Expertwannabe: of course, I've forgotten to include it. Actually, you must do it otherwise it won't compile ;)

Comment: @BlackBear Thank you very much! now I understand about Generics. :)